# Geth keep truncating ancient chain + rewind blockchain ? Why ? 

Tags: go-ethereum

Maybe it's a newbe question but I notice that when I restart Geth it always "rewind blockchain" ? Why is this ?

Here is example output:

```
INFO [11-08|22:02:47.152] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
INFO [11-08|22:02:47.166] Enabling metrics collection
INFO [11-08|22:02:47.168] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [11-08|22:02:47.209] Set global gas cap                       cap=25000000
INFO [11-08|22:02:47.212] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=1023.00MiB dirty=1024.00MiB
INFO [11-08|22:02:47.215] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\Ethereum\data\geth\chaindata cache=2.00GiB handles=8192
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.382] Opened ancient database                  database=C:\Ethereum\ancient
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.403] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, YOLO v1: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.409] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\Ethereum\data\geth\ethash count=3
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.411] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Ethash count=2
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.415] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[65 64 63]" network=1 dbversion=8
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.428] Loaded most recent local header          number=6117739 hash="35c303…a32642" td=5897858276445856298151 age=2y3mo1w
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.431] Loaded most recent local full block      number=1       hash="5708b6…36a4aa" td=34351349760            age=32m28s
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.434] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=6083811 hash="b8e2f3…22291d" td=5776340386706467872922 age=2y3mo2w
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.437] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=11218639
WARN [11-08|22:02:53.441] Head state missing, repairing            number=1        hash="5708b6…36a4aa"
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.445] Loaded most recent local header          number=6117739  hash="35c303…a32642" td=5897858276445856298151 age=2y3mo1w
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.448] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0        hash="d4e567…cb8fa3" td=17179869184            age=51y7mo4d
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.452] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=1        hash="5708b6…36a4aa" td=34351349760            age=32m28s
INFO [11-08|22:02:53.455] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=11218639
ERROR[11-08|22:02:53.456] Truncating ancient chain                 from=6117739 to=1
WARN [11-08|22:02:53.458] Rewinding blockchain                     target=1
```

Why there's an ERROR ? and why it rewinding blockchain ? It been already running for 2 days

P.S. Geth version:

```
Geth
Version: 1.9.23-stable
Git Commit: 8c2f271528f9cccf541c6ea1c022e98407f26872
Git Commit Date: 20201015
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.15
Operating System: windows
GOPATH=C:\Users\User1\go
GOROOT=go
```

P.S.S. Suprise suprise ! Geth do rewind to blockchain in the middle of downloading (????)

Here is example 1:

```
INFO [11-09|15:33:58.621] Imported new state entries               count=1147 elapsed=5.002ms    processed=537599526 pending=19918  trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47374 unexpected=163168
WARN [11-09|15:33:59.321] Rewinding blockchain                     target=1119323
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.323] Imported new state entries               count=442  elapsed=2.002ms    processed=537599968 pending=19645  trieretry=2    coderetry=0 duplicate=47374 unexpected=163168
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.436] Loaded most recent local header          number=1119323  hash="792b16…c7cad2" td=8839796181663421421    age=4y8mo3w
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.441] Loaded most recent local full block      number=1        hash="c27374…653e3a" td=34351349760            age=1h7m21s
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.449] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=1106582  hash="5d452a…179911" td=8619120516308524493    age=4y8mo4w
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.454] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=11223505
WARN [11-09|15:33:59.457] Rolled back chain segment                header=1121372->1119323 fast=1106582->1106582 block=1->1 reason=nil
WARN [11-09|15:33:59.464] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=922ce45be17deadd err="action from bad peer ignored: header request timed out"
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.465] Commit new mining work                   number=2        sealhash="da3b25…cd35f6" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="999.9µs"
INFO [11-09|15:33:59.469] Mining aborted due to sync
WARN [11-09|15:34:00.231] Multiple headers for single request      peer=ab077d32e906411f headers=0
WARN [11-09|15:34:00.235] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ab077d32e906411f err="action from bad peer ignored: multiple headers (0) for single request"
INFO [11-09|15:34:00.235] Commit new mining work                   number=2        sealhash="41ebbb…f8107d" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=0s
INFO [11-09|15:34:00.241] Mining aborted due to sync
```

and here is example 2:

```
INFO [11-09|15:37:53.814] Imported new state entries               count=2519 elapsed=16.002ms   processed=537876097 pending=20752  trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
WARN [11-09|15:37:54.092] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=ffaae0cfd5f7a078
INFO [11-09|15:37:54.461] Imported new state entries               count=2250 elapsed=17.000ms   processed=537878347 pending=19328  trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:37:54.985] Imported new block headers               count=640  elapsed=161.001ms  number=1324502  hash="baf130…4a6310" age=4y7mo3w
INFO [11-09|15:37:55.115] Imported new block receipts              count=2048 elapsed=581.000ms  number=1282674  hash="32a3b4…dd18cd" age=4y7mo4w   size=8.29MiB
INFO [11-09|15:37:55.158] Imported new state entries               count=2330 elapsed=21.999ms   processed=537880677 pending=17880  trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:37:55.527] Imported new block receipts              count=2048 elapsed=393.004ms  number=1284722  hash="757ed6…95d108" age=4y7mo4w   size=3.06MiB
INFO [11-09|15:37:55.927] Imported new block receipts              count=2048 elapsed=379.001ms  number=1286770  hash="6df027…442258" age=4y7mo4w   size=3.28MiB
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.145] Imported new state entries               count=2435 elapsed=16.000ms   processed=537883112 pending=16308  trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.227] Imported new block receipts              count=1053 elapsed=285.999ms  number=1287823  hash="ae3649…4d73d4" age=4y7mo3w   size=2.19MiB
WARN [11-09|15:37:56.358] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=b775c09a1c98fdc6
WARN [11-09|15:37:56.361] Rewinding blockchain                     target=1322453
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.361] Imported new state entries               count=12   elapsed="999.3µs"  processed=537883124 pending=16301  trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.498] Loaded most recent local header          number=1322453  hash="0ef5bc…67c11f" td=13259942553865648289   age=4y7mo3w
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.504] Loaded most recent local full block      number=1        hash="c27374…653e3a" td=34351349760            age=1h11m18s
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.510] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=1287823  hash="ae3649…4d73d4" td=12351705501519696731   age=4y7mo3w
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.515] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=11223522
WARN [11-09|15:37:56.519] Rolled back chain segment                header=1324502->1322453 fast=1287823->1287823 block=1->1 reason="syncing canceled (requested)"
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.535] Imported new block receipts              count=518  elapsed=208.001ms  number=1288341  hash="de1e4b…784fe8" age=4y7mo3w   size=1.12MiB
WARN [11-09|15:37:56.546] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=b775c09a1c98fdc6 err=timeout
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.547] Commit new mining work                   number=2        sealhash="896fd0…128733" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=1.000ms
INFO [11-09|15:37:56.557] Mining aborted due to sync
INFO [11-09|15:38:06.194] Imported new state entries               count=195  elapsed=0s         processed=537883319 pending=2519   trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:38:06.603] Imported new state entries               count=266  elapsed=0s         processed=537883585 pending=3038   trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:38:07.349] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=3.999ms    number=1288533  hash="ef265e…f98788" age=4y7mo3w   ignored=192
INFO [11-09|15:38:07.699] Imported new state entries               count=278  elapsed=0s         processed=537883863 pending=3351   trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=47856 unexpected=163895
INFO [11-09|15:38:07.728] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=60.997ms   number=1290261  hash="368d5a…dfddd0" age=4y7mo3w   ignored=1728
INFO [11-09|15:38:07.819] Imported new block receipts              count=13   elapsed=16.999ms   number=1288354  hash="5026ba…602474" age=4y7mo3w   size=15.71KiB
```

Comment: how are you starting geth? what is the commands and what do you give as parameters ? are you using Docker?

Comment: I'd say it is normal, it happens when there was a chain reorganization and the node has chosen the orphaned branch. On restart perhaps it is doing extra checks to ensure everything is correct by rewinding a few blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this even though I did a graceful shutdown. Most times when I shutdown to apply a patch or upgrade geth all is good but every now and again it does this:
INFO [02-11|14:37:18.150] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=14,180,380
ERROR[02-11|14:37:18.151] Truncating ancient chain                 from=14,178,405 to=3
WARN [02-11|14:37:18.153] Rewinding blockchain                     target=3

Its decide to rewind back to the beginning we're talking maybe 2 to 3 days to rewind back to the start. Just can't fathom why it decides to rewind.